# remove spacing and add dash between words by javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying remove spacing from dynamic content coming from PHP and try to processing the statement by javascript
Example

```js
var str  = "Good- moring Pepol ";
var sgetvenu=  str.replace(/\s/g, '');
var rgetvenu = sgetvenu.split(' ').join('-');
document.getElementById("results").innerHTML= rgetvenu;
```

```html
<div id="results">

</div>
```

the result is `Good-moringPepol`
but I am looking the result to be `Good-moring-Pepol`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match one or more dashes or spaces, and replace with a single dash:

```js
var str  = "Good- moring Pepol ";
document.getElementById("results").textContent = str.trim().replace(/[ -]+/g, '-');
```

```html
<div id="results">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the String replace and to LowerCase methods, for example:

```
var str  = "Good- moring Pepol ";
str = str.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase(); //new object assigned to var str
```